Speechbrains SpeakerRecognition saves short cuts/links/symlinks of used audio files in working directory
I use the speaker recognition of speechbrain using the Python language:
from speechbrain.inference.speaker import SpeakerRecognition
and I load a model in the following way
model = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb",                                                    savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", run_opts={"device":"cuda"}).
Everything works very well.
However, it saves short cuts/links/symlinks to the audio files that I give to speechbrain in my working directory. Is there any way to suppress this?
Code example:
model = 
SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa- 
voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb",                                                      
run_opts={"device":"cuda"})

# collects the distances of the speaker reference and the samples
dist_dict = {}

path_reference = os.path.join(reference_dir, reference_file_name)

for dir_name in samples_dir_names:

    dir_path = os.path.join(samples_dir, dir_name)

    dist_dict[dir_path] = {}

    file_paths_names = get_all_file_paths_and_names(
        os.path.join(samples_dir, dir_name),ext=ext)
    
    file_paths = file_paths_names['file_paths']
    file_names = file_paths_names['file_names']
    
    for file_path, file_name in zip(file_paths, file_names):
        
        duration = librosa.get_duration(filename=file_path)
        if duration >= duration_val:
            print(f'\t{file_name}')
            print(f'\t\tduration: {duration}')

            dist = compare_audios(path_reference,
                                  file_path,
                                  model
                                  )
            
            dist_dict[dir_path][file_name] = dist

# ------------------------------------------------- #
def compare_audios(speaker1_path,
               speaker2_path,
               model):
"""
INPUT
    speaker1_path (str): Path to the audo file
        for the first speaker.
    speaker2_path (str): Path to the audo file
        for the second speaker.
"""



score, prediction = model.verify_files(speaker1_path,
                                             speaker2_path)

return {'score': score[0].cpu().item(),
        'prediction': prediction[0].cpu().item()}

It exists a discussion about it but no solution until today: https://github.com/speechbrain/speechbrain/pull/1303
